# In Excel how can I get a percentage of a fraction with a dynamic denominator

Tags: excel, format, cell, percentage, fractions

My issue is that I want to get a percentage from an cell where if the user writes 50/100 I don't want it to round down to 1/2, even though the percentage is 50% I don't want the cell to change it to 1/2, it should remain as 50/100.

For example if I have a staff member filling in orders and there is a total of 300 order I would like to see what progress they have done in both quantity and percentage?

I've tried numerous things but Excel will always convert it to a fraction.

Any help will do...thanks

Comment: If I input in a cell `50/100` excel shows `50/100` and does not change anything O.o???

Comment: Why is it so hard to show sample data, expected results and original effort? Read [mcve] and [ask]. You've been here before and you should know better.

Comment: It's ok I solved it.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to do a work around and send values to a hidden cell and do some conversions there.

My issue was that Excel formats a cell with the fraction format of 50/100 to 1/2 as in a half. I wanted the values of 50/10 to stay but still representing the 50%.